# Potential SwiftUI ZStack Transition bug when pressed rapidly

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I want to make a modal that works cross platform on iOS and Mac.

The issue is if I toggle the modal rapidly—there's a strange behavior. Attached GIF with the weird behavior below. Is this SwiftUI Bug?

If not, What did I do wrong?

EDIT: more info.
Without animation and transition, the interaction works as expected.

[image: GIF]

Here's the code on Playground

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport


struct CView: View {
    @State var isShown = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
            ZStack {
                Color.green
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Open").onTapGesture {
                            self.isShown = true
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .zIndex(0)
            if self.isShown {
                ZStack {
                    Color.red
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Close").onTapGesture {
                                self.isShown = false
                            }
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
                .animation(.easeInOut)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .zIndex(1)

            }
        }
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(CView())
``


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/21z7z.gif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution. Tested with Xcode 11.5b

[image: demo]

```
struct CView: View {
    @State private var isShown = false
    @State private var showing = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white // needed ??
            ZStack {
                Color.green
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Open").onTapGesture {
                            self.isShown = true
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }.disabled(showing)        // << inactive on in-progress
//                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) // ?? bad visibility
            .zIndex(1) // by default it is always 0, so make above white
            if self.isShown {
                ZStack {
                    Color.red
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Text("Close").onTapGesture {
                                self.isShown = false
                            }
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                .transition(AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom))
                .animation(.easeInOut)
//                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)      // ??
                .zIndex(2)       // top-most
                .onAppear {
                    self.showing = true
                }
                .onDisappear {
                    self.showing = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I was going to do something similar but it feels like a hack before. Well, better get things going!

Do you know if the previous one is a bug / is it an expected behavior?